How to setup the DISPLAY in a Ubuntu Linux docker container? Everything is inside Windows OS
I am in Windows 11 PC environment.
I am using the Docker Container.
    docker pull ubuntu
    docker run -ti --rm ubuntu bash
Now I am inside the Ubuntu Linux env. The problem here I cann't setup the DISPLAY to work properly for me.
The message is "Could not initialize GTK!  Is DISPLAY env var/xhost set?". GTK is the GUI app name only.
I have tried quite a bit of settings based on the suggestions.
Thank you very much!

This is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531202, but you haven't provided enough information to know.  For example ... does the Java app actually need to use a display ... or not?   And what settings have you tried?

@StephenC with the Ubuntu linux terminal working, I can only view some text files content. For example, if I want to open some GVIM or view some simulation waveforms, they won't pop up.

@StephenC Looks like I need to install some X server on the Windows first. Let me try out first.

Either way ... it is clear from your comments that this question about using software not creating software.  It is off-topic.
